# What's the term for a schema that has field+value column rather than individual columns?

Tags: design-pattern

I sometimes see a schema pattern where instead of:

```
|id|mystring|myinteger|mysecondstring|
| 1|hello   |        1|world!        |
```

the table looks like:

```
|field         |value |
|mystring      |hello |
|myinteger     |     1|
|mysecondstring|world!|
```

i.e. the columns are not homogenous, and essentially not typed (everything must be a string, so that string values are possible).

Does this style of schema have a name?

(I would like to convince people to not use this, and it would help if I can find articles about it, but that's very difficult without knowing what it's called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's referred to as the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model